# Is Stack Exchange selling data?

Tags: discussion

I have Asked question here
 [Magento2 : Change Customer name Prefix to Radio button from Dropdown on Checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227177/magento2-change-customer-name-prefix-to-radio-button-from-dropdown-on-checkout) 

Today I have searched on google and I found that my same question on two websites (may be there are many but I couldn't reached thare).

https://techutils.in/blog/2018/06/02/stackbounty-magento2-checkout-customer-magento2-change-customer-name-prefix-to-radio-button-from-dropdown-on-checkout-page/

https://www.questarter.com/q/magento2-change-customer-name-prefix-to-radio-button-from-dropdown-on-checkout-page-10_227177.html

Comment: May be this helpful https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79435/what-is-stack-overflows-business-model

Answer (score 16):

Actually those are not examples of Stack Exchange selling data, they are "scrapers" that are simply pulling the data off Stack Exchange sites and reproducing the content in an attempt to drive traffic to their site. You can see at the bottom of the page contributions you make are licensed under "cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution", so under some circumstances it's perfectly OK to reproduce posts elsewhere as long as they have proper attribution.

The first site has some attribution, because the "get this bounty" button points back at the question here but seems to be missing some required details such as a link to the license. The second site doesn't seem to comply with those rules at all from what I can see.

You can find full details here of the requirements of sites re-using content and what to do to report those sites if they don't follow those requirements:

[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do)

Comment: Thanks for information